# Custom View Snackbar from XML file will not display bottom of screen

Tags: android, android-layout

We have tried two ways to display a Custom Snackbar (1) as a masquerading Dialog which will not move to the bottom of the screen It does however not dismiss the current Activity view just makes it opaque. I know why it is in the center of the screen but I am not able to move it to the bottom. (2) next is a view that takes over the entire screen because it is a new content view that I am guessing dismisses the current Activity view BUT it is at the bottom of the screen.
So my question is how to use design number 1 and move the Dialog to the bottom of screen?
Second question how to stop the new view in design number 2 from dismissing the view of the current Activity? After careful reading and little thought and extreme testing I do not think this is possible! I have posted the code for my two methods below. The XML file uses a Relative Layout as the base container.

```
    public void seeSB(){

        setContentView(R.layout.custom_snackbar);
        // Line of Code above shows XML file
        // Line of code tested but no control over the "viewMyLayout"
        //LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ListActivity.this);
        //final View viewMyLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_snackbar, null);
        //viewMyLayout.setEnabled(true);

        Button btnAB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAB);
        btnAB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // viewMyLayout.setEnabled(false);
                // Line above does not function
                // CODE BELOW WORKS BUT FAR FROM elegant
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
                //Intent intent = new Intent(ListActivity.this, ListActivity.class );
                //startActivity(intent);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I WAS Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    public void displaySB(){

        final Dialog openSnack = new Dialog(context);
        openSnack.setContentView(R.layout.custom_snackbar);
        Button btnAB = (Button)openSnack.findViewById(R.id.btnAB);
        TextView tvSB =(TextView)openSnack.findViewById(R.id.tvSB);
        //Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ListActivity.this);
        //dialog.setContentView(Bottom);

        // if YES delete Master Password from TABLE_MPW
        btnAB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openSnack.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I WAS Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        openSnack.show();
    }
```

Comment: so you want a snackbar at the bottom of the activity without dismissing the activity. Right?

Comment: @AlokKumarVerma YES I can accomplish this using the design.widget.CoordinatorLayout but making a custom XML file will provide less code when I use that XML file for styling for different size devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is far from functional in my book because the method design has just one Custom Snackbar to look at so you need to work on how to have multiple fixed Custom Snackbars. One suggestion might be to have multiple sub views in your parent view and call the sub view you want. I will post just the sub view I added to the parent XML file and the not so real dynamic method to implement which is implemented in this case with a button click. For this to work in a real application the code would need be called from some method or event. 
You might consider a switch statement for multiple views ? ? ?

TAKE NOTE THE RELATIVE LAYOUT has its visibility set to GONE at the start

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/hold_snackbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/color_Black"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/snackbar_text"
        android:textColor="@color/color_Yellow"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="350dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@color/color_Transparent"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text="@string/snackbar_action"
        android:textColor="@color/color_Red"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Notice the View subViewGroup is declared when the Activity starts

```
View subViewGroup;

        public void makeSB(View view) {
        subViewGroup = findViewById(R.id.hold_snackbar);
        subViewGroup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        seeSB();
    }

        public void seeSB(){

            Button btnAB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAB);
            btnAB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               subViewGroup.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I WAS Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Countdown Timer to close a Snackbar with no Action Button

```
    public void makeCDT(View view) {

    cdt = new CountDownTimer(5000, 100) {
        //  5 sec  5000,100
        // 10 sec 10000,100
        @Override
        public void onTick(long secsUntilFinished) {
            etCPW.setText(String.valueOf(secsUntilFinished / 1000));
            //etCPW.setText("seconds remaining: " + secsUntilFinished / 1000);
            subViewGroup = findViewById(R.id.SB_NO_ACTION);
            subViewGroup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            etCPW.setText("Counter Done");
            subViewGroup.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            if(cdt!=null){
                cdt.cancel();
            }
        }
    };
    cdt.start();

    }
```

Comment: @James_Duh solved the snack bar with no Action button just attach a CountDownTimer and after what ever duration you set it will close I seldom use timers so this was a fun project enhancement I will add the code to my Answer